# Using pd.apply() with shift to compare adjacent rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to compare adjacent rows on two separate columns. I have a `dataframe` with two columns, `Letter` and `Boolean_Value`. I would like to create a new column, `New Col` in which the value is `True` or `False`.

For the value to be true:

The next row down (higher index) must share the same `Letter` value and the the next row down must have a `Boolean_Value` of True.

for the value to be false:

All other scenarios

My code, yields all false values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', False],
                        ['A', True],
                        ['B', False],
                        ['B', False],
                        ['B', True]]
                  ,columns=['Letter', 'Boolean_Value'])

def my_test2(row):
    try:
        if row['Letter'].shift(1) == row['Letter'] and row['Boolean_Value'].shift(1) == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False

df['New Col'] = df.apply(my_test2, axis=1)

print df
```

Yields:

```
  Letter Boolean_Value New Col
0      A         False   False
1      A          True   False
2      B         False   False
3      B         False   False
4      B          True   False
```

Desired output:

```
  Letter Boolean_Value New Col
0      A         False   True
1      A          True   False
2      B         False   False
3      B         False   True
4      B          True   False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

```
df['new_col'] = (df.Letter == df.Letter.shift(-1)) & df.Boolean_Value.shift(-1)

  Letter Boolean_Value new_col
0      A         False    True
1      A          True   False
2      B         False   False
3      B         False    True
4      B          True   False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', False],
                        ['A', True],
                        ['B', False],
                        ['B', False],
                        ['B', True]]
                  ,columns=['Letter', 'Boolean_Value'])


df['New Col'] = df['Letter'] == df['Letter'].shift(-1)
df['New Col'] = df['New Col'] != df['Boolean_Value'].shift(1)

print(df)
```